# Nuget for PowerShell Projects in Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, nuget

How can I install nuget packages for my PowerShell Projects in Visual Studio 2015? I have tried to do it with both the PowerShell Module Project and PowerShell Script Project. I have installed PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2015.

When I open these projects, the Default project in the Package Manager Console is empty. Here is a screenshot of what I mean.

[image: empty Default project:]

When I try to install a nuget package, e.g. [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester), I get the following error.

[image: PM> Install-Package Pester Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found. At line:1 char:1 + Install-Package Pester + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundExc eption + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.Inst allPackageCommand PM>]

Comment: Any Advance? I am ring to run tests, but I get:"Failed to load Pester module. The specified module 'Pester' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory."

Comment: @XtianGIS Unfortunately I don't have any updates on this question. Your comment may be a different question altogether.

Comment: you are correct, but looking for solution to my issue, I face the same issue that you faced. either way I already raised my hand and ask the proper question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread might be outdated and is rather old but my older article with some possible solutions might help here. I tested current state and still, no support inside VS 2015 for PowerShell project and NuGet packages together.

the current state is :

1. go with https://chocolatey.org/ and install it on your dev box (and CI) => you install pester globally with : **choco install pester** and update it if needed.
2. **use old packages.config** and update by hand version number and run **nuget restore** (nuget update will no longer work for this type of solution).
3. version whole pester into repo and call it directly. you can use **nuget install pester** for this (if you have nuget in path somewhere)

The link : http://rostacik.net/2015/12/16/how-to-use-nuget-packages-even-with-powershell-projects-with-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: well it won't, its my page. :) but I agree with you. my bad. 

user can just read the essential information here and doesn't have to hit my page , sure.

so in a nutshell :
1. either you go with [https://chocolatey.org/](https://chocolatey.org) and install it on your dev box (and CI) => you install pester globally with :
**choco install pester** and update it if needed.

2. **use old packages.config** and update by hand version number and run **nuget restore** (nuget update will no longer work for this type of solution).

3. version whole pester into repo and call it directly.